# WordPress Project Information

Tags: design

I’m a student of IT, now we are studying Software development, architecture, design, methodologies, etc.

We should choose an open source project to get information about it and write a well documented work. I chose WordPress because I’ve used it before, I have currently a project running over it, I have changed some core files and plugins, and cause I like PHP!

But I’m having troubles finding some information about the project, becasue most of the post talk baout how to develop with WordPress and not about HOW IS WORDPRESS DEVELOPED.

- I would like to know about WordPress development methodology? Does development team follow an agile methodology?

  I have read Philosophy and information about bug tracker, tickets and now I’m reading about release philosophy. But nothing in particular about methodology.
  Somewhere I could read they use Agile methodology.
- I will need information about software architecture. I have read WordPress is based on Event-driven paradigm, I have some post to investigate more about this. But I’m sure there is more architecture patterns in WordPress.
- In the future I will start researching information about Design Patterns inside WordPress core, I’m stuck on previous points for now, If you give me some guidelines about this part or references to read about I would be grateful.

I’M NOT ASKING YOU TO MAKE MY WORK! I’m just asking for help, information or references. Of course I can share my work when I finish my research, and I will!

Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure this type of question is the right fit for our QA format. It may be better suited over at the [Official WordPress Forums](https://wordpress.org/support/forums/). You may also find it beneficial to check out their [slack channel(s)](https://make.wordpress.org/chat/) where most the core contributors hang out.

Comment: Yes, sorry I thougth about it. I'm looking for info everywhere, because I can't find anything. I have asked there too. If it must be closed I'm sorry. My bad.

Comment: Maybe you should ask in the [SLACK channel](https://make.wordpress.org/chat/) of the core leads, there lead a release. She have more background, history that is no public. You find all release leads under the version no of the [roadmap page](https://wordpress.org/about/roadmap/)

Answer (score 1):

The [Core contributors handbook](https://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/) provides a lot of detail about the development methodology and standards.

Answer (score 1):

You would benefit greatly from hanging out in the WordPress official Slack. They have regular meetings you can lurk in.